# How to change pages using a function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, access-token, typescript2.0

When a user logs in and clicks the button, a function is called and this function calls a function that returns a Promise. When the user logs in, the href property is responsible for changing pages. I need to change the page inside the function login though because I tried using a ternary on the href, but it does not wait for the function that returns a Promise to be returned.

My purpose is to change to the /dashboard page after the access token is brought

Function login:

```
 const login = async () => {
        const response = await LoginService({email, password})
        if (response.access_token) {
            setReturned(true)
            console.log('ACCESS TOKEN IS RETURNED')
           } else {
            throw new Error('NO ACCESS TOKEN')
        }

    }

                       




<Button color='primary' onClick={login} className='btn-next' block href={'/dashboard'} >
                                Login
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing concerns here. The buttons are supposed to fire actions and you are using an anchor tag to do both actions and redirects so I'd say you need to change a little bit the approach here.

Hacky solution:

```js
const login = async () => {
  const response = await LoginService({ email, password });
  if (response.access_token) {
    setReturned(true);
    console.log('ACCESS TOKEN IS RETURNED');

    window.location.href = '/dashboard';
  } else {
    throw new Error('NO ACCESS TOKEN');
  }
};
```

```html
<Button color='primary' onClick={login} className='btn-next'>
  Login
</Button>
```

I'd like to recommend you https://reactrouter.com/ for a better app routing strategy.